# Time part is missing when using convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a date in a column like this (`2016-06-01 21:50:00.000`) - `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

I am trying to convert it to like this  --> (`01/06/2016 21:50:00.000`) `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS`

I've tried the following;

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CONVERT(DATETIME, MYDATECOLUMN, 101), 103)
FROM MYTABLE
```

**Time part is missing**.

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this?

I don't have permission to change data in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MYDATECOLUMN, 103) + ' '  + convert(VARCHAR(8), MYDATECOLUMN, 14) 
FROM MYTABLE
```

IF you want to show millisecond also change varchar size from 8 to 12 in second part

```
  select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MYDATECOLUMN, 103) + ' '  + convert(VARCHAR(12), MYDATECOLUMN, 14) 
   FROM MYTABLE
```

Comment: Size of the VARCHAR should be 12 for the second part. 8 is not sufficient.

Comment: @ChathurangaRanasinghe ya..if millisecond needs to show it should be 12

Comment: @Sachu: Thanks Sachu

Comment: @shan glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `103` for the date part and then `CAST` the date_column to `TIME` for getting the time part.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(), 103) +
       ' ' + CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) AS VARCHAR(20));
```

**Result**

```
02/05/2016 12:43:05.9930000
```

Or if you want to remove the milliseconds part,

**QUERY**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(), 103) + 
       ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108);
```

**Result**

```
02/05/2016 12:43:30
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Cast(MYDATECOLUMN as date), 103) +
   ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),  Cast(MYDATECOLUMN as time),  113);
```